# Pandas replace tuple like value from pd.cut with a integer

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
  count
  (1.386, 3.045]
  (1.386, 3.045]
  (0.692, 1.386]
  (1.386, 3.045]
  (1.386, 3.045]
  (1.386, 3.045]
  (1.386, 3.045]
  (0.692, 1.386]
```

I would like to create labels for each interval

Above dataframe is a result of pd.cut function like below

```
pd.cut(t['count'],bins=p_breaks,labels=[1,2,3,4,5],include_lowest=True,duplicates='drop')
```

but it resulted in an error

So, I removed the `labels` argument and I got an ouptut like below

```
  (1.386, 3.045]
  (1.386, 3.045]
  (0.692, 1.386]
  (1.386, 3.045]
  (1.386, 3.045]
  (1.386, 3.045]
  (1.386, 3.045]
  (0.692, 1.386]
```

Now, I would like to replace these items. So, I tried the below

```
t['count'].replace((0.692, 1.386),1)
t['count'].replace((1.386, 3.045),2)
```

I expect my output to be like as below

```
count
2
2
1
2
2
2
2
1
```

Comment: What's your inital df? Whats the exact error?

Comment: Initial dataframe had count values such as 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 etc. I applied log transformation and then used standard scaler to scale the variable.

Comment: Once that is done, I applied `pd.cut` function which resulted in error.. https://medium.datadriveninvestor.com/valueerror-bin-edges-must-be-unique-71512ff2257d

Comment: what is the value of `p_break`?

Comment: `0.6931471805599453, 0.6931471805599453, 1.3862943611198906, 3.044522437723423`

Comment: Give your entire dataframe or a part of it you can do df.to_dict and copy paste the code here, like this we can reproduce the error in our own IDE and show us an example of the desired DF output not just the column count, out of context it's hard to understand or even guess what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use `replace`, you can use `.cat.codes` to get the ordinal values assigned to the corresponding intervals

```
t['count'] = pd.cut(t['count'], bins=p_breaks, duplicates='drop', include_lowest=True).cat.codes + 1
```